# Receive JSON with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

With Node JS I'm trying to do simple user signup, sending `username`, `email` and `password` to the `'/newuser'` endpoint, which can be seen in `user.js`.
The header gets sent correctly and I'm able to see it in the console, but I can not access the `req.body` part that I'm interested in. I'm using the `body-parser` express middleware as suggested in the documentation of express.

If I print out `req.body`, only `[object Object]` is printed, if I print out the **whole** `req` object I can not see the parameters anywhere and if I try to `JSON.parse(req.body)`, then of course `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` shows up. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

### JavaScript on frontend

I'm doing it this way, and it should work like this (I've also tried it with ajax, but it also doesn't work, same error). But the data I'm sending is definitely correct, if I print it out before sending, it is a valid JSON.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/newuser');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
  username: data.username,
  password: data.password,
  email: data.email
}));
```

### server.js

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var hogan  = require('hogan-express');
var http_module = require('http');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json('application/json'));

app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: true}));
app.engine('html', hogan);
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy

const partials = {
  header: 'partials/header',
  footer: 'partials/footer'
};

require('./routes')(app, partials);

const http = http_module.Server(app);

http.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.info('Running on http://localhost:%s', app.get('port'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

### routes.js

```
// Routes
module.exports = (app, partials) => {
  require('./home')(app, partials);
  require('./signup')(app, partials);
  require('./user')(app, partials);
  require('./404')(app, partials);
};
```

### user.js

```
module.exports = (app, partials) => {
    app.post('/newuser', (req, res, next) => {

        console.log(req.header('Content-Type'))
        console.log(req.body) // this prints [object Object]
        console.log(JSON.parse(req.body)) // this throws SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    });
};
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I pasted all your code and it works fine for me (except the JSON.parse obviously). I'm curious what do you get if you log out `typeof req.body` and `Object.keys(req.body)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've used body-parser's `json` parser, the JSON is **already parsed** by the time you get it (which is why you see `[object Object]` if you `console.log` it — that's what you get when you coerce an object to string and it doesn't have any special `toString` defined for it*).

To access the properties on the object you were sent, access them on `req.body`:

```
app.post('/newuser', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.header('Content-Type'))
    console.log(req.body.username); // <====
    console.log(req.body.password); // <====
    console.log(req.body.email);    // <====
});
```

With that code, I see the POSTed data when I run your code locally.

---

* Except that as JJJ points out below, if you're *really* using `console.log`, you should be seeing a representation of the object, not `[object Object]`, in just about any version of Node. Perhaps you're using something else that's coercing to string? Or using middleware you haven't shown which might overwrite `req.body` with `String(req.body)`?

Comment: If you do `console.log(JSON.parse(x))` and `x` is valid JSON, you shouldn't see "[object Object]" because the console does print out basic objects with their contents. So there might be something else going on.

Comment: @JJJ: Hmmm, depends on the console implementation, but you're right, Node v4 and v8 both show a representation of the object, not `[object Object]`.

Comment: @JJJ: However, if I make the change above, I do see the POSTed data.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is correct. You should simply be able to access the user details from `req.body`.

```
module.exports = (app, partials) => {
    app.post('/newuser', (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(req.header('Content-Type'))
        console.log(req.body.email)
        console.log(req.body.password)
        console.log(req.body.username)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
    });
};
```

In order for it not to print `[object Object]`, I used `JSON.stringify()` method as `req.body` is already a JavaScript object.